# Substitute only one group when dealing with an unknown number of capturing groups

Tags: c#, regex

Assuming I have this input:

**/green/blah/agriculture/apple/blah/**

I'm only trying to capture and replace the occurrence of apple (need to replace it with orange), so I have this regex

```
var regex =  new Regex("^/(?:green|red){1}(?:/.*)+(apple){1}(?:/.*)");
```

So I'm grouping sections of the input, but as non-capturing, and only capturing the one I'm concerned with. According to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewy2t5e0(v=vs.110).aspx) **$`** will retrieve everything before the match in the input string, and **$'** will get everything after, so theoretically the following should work:

```
"$`Orange$'"
```

But it only retrieves the match ("apple").

Is it possible to do this with just substitutions and **NOT** match evaluators and looping through groups?

The issue is that apple can occur anywhere in that url scheme, hence an unknown number of capture groups.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve what you want, I slightly changed your regex.

The new regex looks like this **look for the updated version at the end of the answer**:

What I am doing here is, I **want** all the other groups to become captured groups. Doing this I can use them as follow:

```
String replacement = "$1Orange$2";
string result = Regex.Replace(text, regex.ToString(), replacement);
```

I am using group 1,2 and 4 and in the middle of everything (where I suspect 'apple') I replace it with `Orange`.

A complete example looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Test
{
  public static void Main()
  {
    String text = "/green/blah/agriculture/apple/blah/hallo/apple";
    var regex =  new Regex("^(/(?:green|red)/(?:[^/]+/)*?)apple(/.*)");
    String replacement = "$1$2Orange$4";
    string result = Regex.Replace(text, regex.ToString(), replacement);
    Console.WriteLine(result);
  }
}
```

And as well a running example is [here](http://ideone.com/5SiRf9)

#### See the updated regex, I needed to change it again to capture things like this:

```
 /green/blah/agriculture/apple/blah/hallo/apple/green/blah/agriculture/apple/blah/hallo/apple
```

With the above regex it matched the last apple and not the first as prio designated. I changed the regex to this:

```
var regex =  new Regex("^(/(?:green|red)/(?:[^/]+/)*?)apple(/.*)");
```

I updated the code as well as the running example.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to replace only the first occurence of `apple` and dont mind about the URL structure then can you use one of the following methods:

**First** simply use `apple` as regex and use the overloaded Replace method.

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
      String text = "/green/blah/agriculture/apple/blah/hallo/apple/green/blah/agriculture/apple/blah/hallo/apple";
      var regex = new Regex(Regex.Escape("apple"));
      String replacement = "Orange";
      string result = regex.Replace(text, replacement.ToString(), 1);
      Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
}
```

[See working Example](http://ideone.com/4XZnKb)

---

**Second** is the use of IndexOf and Substring which could be much quick as the use of the regex classes.

See the following Example:

```
   class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string search = "apple";
            string text = "/green/blah/agriculture/apple/blah/hallo/apple/green/blah/agriculture/apple/blah/hallo/apple";
            int idx = text.IndexOf(search);
            int endIdx = idx + search.Length;
            int secondStrLen = text.Length - endIdx;
            if (idx != -1 && idx < text.Length && endIdx < text.Length && secondStrLen > -1)
            {
                string first = text.Substring(0, idx);
                string second = text.Substring(endIdx, secondStrLen);
                string result = first + "Orange" + second;
                Console.WriteLine(result);
            }
        }
    }
```

[Working Example](http://ideone.com/7eX0OZ)